# Why is the modal not working after the button is clicked?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have the following HTML, but the modal is not working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Rooms</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/rooms.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                    Create Room
                </button>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.7.1/socket.io.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-+NaO7d6gQ1YPxvc/qHIqZEchjGm207SszoNeMgppoqD/67fEqmc1edS8zrbxPD+4RQI3gDgT/83ihpFW61TG/Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="/static/rooms.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using Bootstrap 5, and I think that my syntax is correct but when I click the button the modal does not show. I have tried it in chrome, and brave browser. Why is this happening?

UPDATE: I have included the cdn links that I used in my local enviroment

Comment: I have forgotten cdn link Bootstrap

Comment: Any messages in the console? Also, you said that you're using BS5 but your code links to BS4

Comment: @j08691 No messages in the console, and also some utility classes like `fw-*`, `ms-*` and others don`t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible reasons why you're encountering this problem:

1. You didn't include Bootstrap's JS.
2. You included Bootstrap's JS incorrectly (e.g., you included both Bootstrap's JS bundle and separate JS files).

If you include Bootstrap's JS correctly, the modal starts working.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
      Create Room
    </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**

You used cdn for Bootstrap 4, but in your code, you're using Bootstrap 5. Also, use a newer Popper version (i.e., `2.11.6`) that is compatible with Bootstrap 5.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Rooms</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/rooms.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Create Room</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.7.1/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha512-+NaO7d6gQ1YPxvc/qHIqZEchjGm207SszoNeMgppoqD/67fEqmc1edS8zrbxPD+4RQI3gDgT/83ihpFW61TG/Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="/static/rooms.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But I a have used the code snippet given in the Bootstrap docs, and everything works except the modal. Also the `fw-*` utility classes don`t work, but with the cdn link that you have shown it works.

Comment: @LeuelAsfaw Can you provide a [mre] then?

Comment: @Unmitigated I have updated my question with the cdn links that I used in my local environment.

Comment: @Unmitigated But they do provide the code snippet in the docs, why does this happen?

Comment: @LeuelAsfaw Link?

Comment: @LeuelAsfaw You were looking at the [Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/), I guess. See the [Bootstrap 5 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4, Use `data-toggle` and `data-target` (instead of `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target`).

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Create Room
</button>
```

See the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).